# MySQL Sum on matching set of data

Tags: mysql, select, sum

This is my first post in this forum. I normally find ans to my problems when search but this is the first time I needed to post this question. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I have a table called "gjournal_main"

```
`dateinput` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Input Date',
`datepaid` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Date of Invoice',
`invoiceno` varchar(12) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Invoice #',
`bookno` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`invoiceno`),
KEY `invoiceno` (`invoiceno`)
```

and another with transaction detials "general_journal" (or items)

```
`eid` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entry ID',
`tid` varchar(12) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Transaction ID or Inv no',
`ref` varchar(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Reference no',
`notes` varchar(30) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Narations',
`accountname` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'AC Title',
`debit` int(12) NOT NULL,
`credit` int(12) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`eid`),
KEY `tid` (`tid`),
KEY `ref` (`ref`)
```

I want to do a search on "bookno" and list all records with matching book number (eg 1254) several invoiceno can have one bookno.
I want results something like this ....

```
------------------------------------------------------
inputdate   |invoiceno |bookno|accounttitle|debit|credit
------------------------------------------------------
2011-05-29  | 1        |1254  |item a      |12   |0
2011-05-29  | 1        |1254  |item b      |0    |3
2011-05-29  | 1        |1254  |item b      |1    |3
                             **TOTAL       |13   |6**
2010-01-06  | 2        |900   |item a      |10   |0
2010-01-06  | 2        |900   |item b      |50   |0
2010-01-06  | 2        |900   |item c      |10   |30
2010-01-06  | 2        |900   |item d      |10   |0
                             **TOTAL       |80   |30**

------------------------------------------------------
```

I want a break with sum of debit and credit  after listing invoice number 1 and so on how can I do that ?

thanks a lot

Comment: Take a look at group by with rollup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using union to stick a line with totals to the individual lines:

```
select
    g.inputdate,
    g.invoiceno,
    g.bookno,
    j.accountname,
    j.debit,
    j.credit,
    1 as recordtype /*invoice line*/
from
    gjournal_main g
    inner join general_journal j on j.tid = g.invoiceno
union all
select
    null,
    null,
    g.invoiceno,
    '** Total',
    sum(j.debit),
    sum(j.credit),
    2 as recordtype /* total */
from
    gjournal_main g
    inner join general_journal j on j.tid = g.invoiceno
group by
    g.invoiceno
order by
    bookno,
    invoiceno,
    recordtype
having
    bookno = 600
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Golez Trol. I have tried the statement and its not giving me the result i want. It shows up total of all the debit and credit colums which match the criteria "Bookno".

Comment: Thanks a lot Golez Trol. I have tried the statement and its not giving me the result i want. It shows up total of all the debit and credit colums which match the criteria "Bookno". also i am not very much familiar with mysql so please forgive me for the stupid questions.. why have to put i,j.g then dot before the column names ?

Comment: Oops. I think I forgot the group by that I have now added in my answer.

Comment: The g and j are *aliases* for the tables. The aliases are specified after the table name. That way you can specify which table the field should be taken from, without specifying the whole table name. I think it adds readability to you queries once you got used to them. You could write just `debit` which would leave you undecisive about the table used (although MySQL will usually know) or you can write `general_journal.debit`, which I think is too long. `j.debit` feels just right. ;-)

Comment: I get following msg when try to run above statements                 "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'having bookno = 600 at line 30"

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I haven't got MySQL available now. Could you remove `having bookno = 600`? If that results in a working query, you can add `where bookno = 600` to both subqueries in the union.

Comment: this worked like a charm after few amendments:select
gjournal_main.dateinput,
gjournal_main.invoiceno,
gjournal_main.bookno,
general_journal.accountname,
general_journal.debit,
general_journal.credit,
1 as recordtype 
from
gjournal_main
inner join general_journal on general_journal.tid = gjournal_main.invoiceno
union all
select
null,
null,
gjournal_main.invoiceno,
'** Total',
sum(general_journal.debit),
sum(general_journal.credit),
2 as recordtype 
from
gjournal_main 
inner join general_journal on general_journal.tid = gjournal_main.invoiceno
group by
gjournal_main.invoiceno WITH ROLLUP
order